# Laravel 5.4 ajax formdata request does not appear while uploading a file over https

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

Right now am working for a chatting application where logged user can send images/documents through the chat. The connection is secured that is it runs on HTTPS. I have the below JS code which sends the attached files in Formdata,

```
        fileChunk = new FormData();
        fileChunk.append('Slice', uploader.fileToBeUploaded.slice(start, end));

        var param = JSON.parse(localStorage["meta_data"]);
        fileChunk.append('NewFileName', encodeURI(param.NewFileName));


        jqxhr = $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: (letchatajax_path + 'UploadChunk?id=' + uploader.currentChunk + "&start=" + start),
            data: (fileChunk),//JSON.stringify
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST'
        }).fail(function (request, error) {
            if (error !== 'abort' && retryCount < uploader.maxRetries) {
                ++retryCount;
                setTimeout(sendNextChunk, uploader.retryAfterSeconds * 1000);
            }
            if (error === 'abort') {
                //displayStatusMessage(cful, "Aborted");
            }
            else {
                if (retryCount === uploader.maxRetries) {
                    //displayStatusMessage(cful, "Upload timed out.");
                    //resetControls();
                    uploader = null;
                }
                else {
                    //displayStatusMessage(cful, "Resuming Upload");
                }
            }
            return;
        }).done(function (state) {
            if (state.error || state.isLastBlock) {
                //cful.displayStatusMessage(cful, state.message);
                return;
            }
            ++cful.currentChunk;
            start = (cful.currentChunk - 1) * cful.blockLength;
            end = Math.min(cful.currentChunk * cful.blockLength, cful.fileToBeUploaded.size);
            retryCount = 0;
            cful.updateProgress(cful);
        });
```

We use Laravel 5.4 and route in the web.php is set as below, `Route::post('/UploadChunk','UWebController@UploadChunk');`

The method definition in the controller is as below:

```
function UploadChunk(Request $request){
    $requestparams = $request->all();

    $model = new UploadFileData();
    $model->FileName    = $requestparams['NewFileName'];


    $FolderName = public_path().'/uatstorageservice/CHAT_FILES/';
    $request->file('Slice')->move($FolderName,  $model->FileName);
}
```

Now at this stage its throwing the error below when I try to read request variable 'Slice' which is related to 'Image' data,

> FatalThrowableError in UWebController.php line 348: to a member function move() on null

Please help.

Comment: the file is not accessible like normal input `$request->input('name');` you need to use  `$request->file('filename');` Read this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files)

Comment: If you can see in the above code I have used the same
$request->file('Slice')->move($FolderName,  $model->FileName);

Comment: but you've used `$requestparams['NewFileName']` before move file, do you want file upload code then please read doc link I sent you.

Comment: Thank you, but the $requestparams['NewFileName'] consists of the 'Name' in which the file has to be moved to the folder  'CHAT_FILES'. Its the name which follows some rules, so that there wouldn't be any duplication and some other constraints.

Comment: are you sure content is sending through AJAX? can you check your console and see what data is being sent?

Comment: Yes I am sure we actually integrated the below third party to upload files in chunks, http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/894/upload-multiple-files-chunks-aspnet-mvc-azure-blob